# How to logout user after registration?

Tags: yii2

The challenge is to redirect users after registration on the login form. Whatever the conflict, it is necessary to logout after signup. Trying to use this code in controller, but it does not work

```
public function actionSignup()
{
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                 Yii::$app->user->logout();
            if (Yii::$app->getUser()->login($user)) {
                return $this->goHome();

            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: So you're attempting to call the `logout()`-function *after* you already returned from the function? I think you can see yourself that that won't really work?

Comment: Well, I was corrected, but still not working

Comment: Yes, because now you are calling the `login()` function after you called the `logout()` function. I still don't get why you want to do all that, but your logout call needs to go in the `if`, right before the `return $this->goHome();`

Comment: If you want to redirect the user to login form then simply redirect him to login action after logout call. Why are you calling the login function after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
siteController.php

public function actionSignup()
    {
        $model = new SignupForm();
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            if ($user = $model->signup()) {
                return $this->goHome();
            }
        }
```

Try this i hope this will help you..Thank You